# Combine every 2 elements in an odd-sized array, leaving the last element on its own (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, string

Here's an example what I'm trying to do:

Let's say I have an array of String with contents {"a","b","c","d","e"}
and and second array with contents {"f","g","h","i"}
I want code that would return {"ab","cd","e"} on the first array and {"fg","hi"} on the second array. I'm using Java. Below is the code I wrote that does not work.

```
    int val;
    if ((ciphertextVals.length % 2) == 0)
        val = ciphertextVals.length/2;
    else
        val = ciphertextVals.length/2 + 1;

    String[] encryptedBinary = new String[val];
    for (int i = 0; i <= ciphertextVals.length-1; i+=2)
    {
        String bin1 = Integer.toBinaryString(ciphertextVals[i]);
        String result;
        if (i == ciphertextVals.length-1)
        {
            result = bin1;
        }
        else
        {
            String bin2 = Integer.toBinaryString(ciphertextVals[i+1]);
            result = bin1 + bin2;
        }
        encryptedBinary[i/2+1] = result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you are making logic complicated, which is not required.
What you said could just be written into codes like this :

```
ArrayList<String> encryptedBinaryList = new ArrayList<>();
String temp = "";
for (int i = 0; i < ciphertextVals.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        temp = Integer.toBinaryString(ciphertextVals[i]);
    } else {
    temp += Integer.toBinaryString(ciphertextVals[i]);
        encryptedBinaryList.add(temp);
    }
}
if (ciphertextVals.length % 2 != 0) {
    encryptedBinaryList.add(temp);
}
String encryptedBinary[] = new String[encryptedBinaryList.size()];
encryptedBinaryList.toArray(encryptedBinary);
```

To check if it is working or not let's replace `Integer.toBinaryString(ciphertextVals[i])` with `Integer.toString(ciphertextVals[i])` and print all the elements of `encryptedBinary`

```
// when int ciphertextVals[] = {6,14,24,24,10,12,14};
614
2424
1012
14
```

Comment: argh. a few seconds too late.

Comment: I put this code in, and it ended up returning an 8-element array when I inputted a 7-element array.

Comment: Maybe. The input is {6,14,24,24,10,12,14}. I'll check and make sure I added the code right.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] input1 = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
    String[] input2 = { "f", "g", "h", "i" };
    String[] input3 = {};

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(combine(input1))); //prints [ab, cd, e]
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(combine(input2))); // prints [fg, hi]
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(combine(input3))); // prints []
}

public static String[] combine(String[] input) {
    boolean isOdd = input.length % 2 != 0;

    int newLength = (input.length + 1) / 2;
    String[] output = new String[newLength];

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length / 2; i++) {
        output[i] = input[2 * i] + input[2 * i + 1];
    }

    if (isOdd) {
        output[output.length - 1] = input[input.length - 1];
    }

    return output;
}
```